# AppExchange Package Usage Info

Tags: api, integration, appexchange, eventlogfile, usagemetrics

I am looking for any **API or Standard object or any way** through which we can get Usage or Sign-in events for packages installed from AppExchange by the users in my Organization.

How can I get this **Usage or sign-in events for any package installed and being used** in my org?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [Package Usage](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.distribution_package_usage.htm&type=5) under setup

Comment: Is there any standard object Or SOQL query through which i can get this Package_Usage ?

Comment: Not from what I have found so far, seems like for Subscribers it is only available through setup - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/app_analytics_managed_package_usage_summaries.htm